# Weird problem with Dwarf Fortress install

Tags: linux-mint, python, configuration, error-handling

Here's the thing. I'm running Mint 19, relatively fresh install. I heard a lot of hype about Dwarf Fortress, and installed it once; then, needing to leave in a hurry, closed it with Control-C. Ever since then, every time I attempt to run it, I get the output:

```
/tmp/dwarf-fortresss7j3cousrun/df: 6: /tmp/dwarf-fortresss7j3cousrun/df: ./libs/Dwarf_Fortress: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/games/dwarf-fortress", line 93, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/games/dwarf-fortress", line 90, in main
    run_df_in_unionfs_with_cleanup(user_run_dir, data_dirs, sys.argv)
  File "/usr/games/dwarf-fortress", line 60, in run_df_in_unionfs_with_cleanup
    run_df_in_unionfs(user_run_dir, data_dirs, args)
  File "/usr/games/dwarf-fortress", line 54, in run_df_in_unionfs
    run_df(tmp_dir, args)
  File "/usr/games/dwarf-fortress", line 46, in run_df
    subprocess.run(cmd).check_returncode()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_returncode self.stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/dwarf-fortresss7j3cousrun/df', '/usr/games/dwarf-fortress']'
returned non-zero exit status 127.
```

Followed by immediate program termination. I have attempted to remove, even purge, and reinstall, dwarf-fortress, only to get the same result. It ran perfectly fine exactly once, and as much as I have been staring at this error, I cannot make sense of it.

It isn't business critical or anything, I'm not technically even a player; but I would really like to know why the program is now failing, and in what manner it was broken by me. It's just too much of a mystery to leave unchecked. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Use the following script to clean your `$XDG_DATA_HOME`/`$HOME` from left-overs and unmount previous `unionfs`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

echo "Killing currently running Dwarf Fortress instances"
killall -q -9 Dwarf_Fortress || true

echo "Removing old Dwarf Fortress unionfs mounts and mount points"
find /tmp/ -maxdepth 1 -name "dwarf-fortress*" \
  -printf "  Found %f\n" \
  \( -exec fusermount -u {} \; -o -true \) \
  -exec rmdir {} \;


UNIONFSDIR="${XDG_DATA_HOME:-"${HOME:?}/.local/share/"}dwarf-fortress/run/.unionfs-fuse"

if [ -d "$UNIONFSDIR" ]; then
  echo "Removing old .unionfs-fuse directory"
  rm -r -- "$UNIONFSDIR"
fi
echo "Done. Run dwarf-fortress and praise Armok!"
```

## Why does this happen?

The `dwarf-fortress` package provided by Ubuntu uses a Python wrapper `/usr/games/dwarf-fortress`. That wrapper creates a secondary `data` hierarchy in `$XDG_DATA_HOME/.local/share/dwarf-fortress/run/.unionfs-fuse`, which gets mounted as `unionfs(8)` together with some other directories.

This enables you to place your mods in your `$XDG_DATA_HOME/.local/share/dwarf-fortress` directory, so you don't need to change the contents of `/usr/share/games/dwarf-fortress`, which is great! However, a `unionfs` must be handled with care and get cleaned up correctly. The Python script failed to do so when you've used <kbd>C-c</kbd> to get out of the game.

Therefore, the `unionfs` is *probably* still mounted, but in a bad state.

## How do I fix it?

So first of all, make sure that the game is completely closed:

```
killall -s KILL Dwarf_Fortress
```

Then make sure that there is no leftover `unionfs` DF mount:

```
mount | grep -a -e dwarf -e unionfs
unionfs on /tmp/dwarf-fortresswvlaptrarun type fuse.unionfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
unionfs on /tmp/dwarf-fortress4ylv2t19run type fuse.unionfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

As you can see, there are currently two on my system. Since both are broken, lets get rid of them with `fusermount -u`:

```
fusermount -u /tmp/dwarf-fortresswvlaptrarun 
fusermount -u /tmp/dwarf-fortress4ylv2t19run
```

And last, but most important, remove the `.unionfs-fuse` in `$XDG_DATA_HOME/dwarf-fortress/run/`. I don't have `XDG_DATA_HOME` set, so I have to use `$HOME`. Check `env` before you accidentally delete the wrong directory!

```
rm -r $HOME/.local/share/dwarf-fortress/run/.unionfs-fuse
```

That's it. Note that the `df_linux` version from [Bay 12 Games](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/) doesn't run into this problems, as it neither uses a Python wrapper nor a Unionfs.

That being said, the [issue was fixed](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/dwarf-fortress/-/commit/aeded710b6c4ed79b2e29f1f174e00659deb8318) in 2019 and is shipped to `bullseye`. Unfortunately, it is *not* fixed in `0.44.12-1`, so `buster` might still be affected.

## How did you come up with this solution?

First of all, I had a look at `file $(which dwarf-fortress)`, which told me that it's a Python script:

```
$ file $(which dwarf-fortress)
/usr/games/dwarf-fortress: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

I then checked the script with any editor and found

```python
def get_user_run_dir():
    old_run_dir = xdg.BaseDirectory.save_data_path('dwarf-fortress')
    new_run_dir = os.path.join(old_run_dir, 'run')
    
    ...

def run_df_in_unionfs(user_run_dir, data_dirs, args):
    mnt_dirs = user_run_dir + "=rw:" + ':'.join(data_dirs)
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(suffix='run', prefix='dwarf-fortress') as tmp_dir:
        cmd = ['unionfs', '-o', 'cow,relaxed_permissions', mnt_dirs, tmp_dir]
        subprocess.run(cmd).check_returncode()
        try:
            run_df(tmp_dir, args)
        finally:
            subprocess.run(['fusermount', '-u', tmp_dir]).check_returncode()
```

which showed that there was at least something to be found in `xdg.BaseDirectory`, which is `$HOME/.local/share` (unless set otherwise). At the same time, `fusermount -u` shows that there is an unmount pending after we quit Dwarf Fortress, and `mount | grep unionfs` confirmed the active mounts in `/tmp`. I got rid of the whole `$XDG_DATA_HOME/dwarf-fortress` directory, and it worked again. With `strace -ff -e trace=execve dwarf-fortress`, I was able to confirm the `unionfs` mounts and found the `.unionfs-fuse` directory.

Comment: I never would have thought of that. It worked perfectly.  I wish I could up-vote this twice.